# Google Map not showing with Ionic 2 native google-maps plugin

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I am trying to embed a google map on my Ionic 2 app, but the map is not showing. 
I took the code from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/
Here is my code : 

**home.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="map_canvas" class="map"></div>
  <button ion-button (click)="loadMap()"></button>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
map: GoogleMap;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public appService: AppService,
              public apiService: ApiService,
              public util: Util,
              private geolocation: Geolocation,
              private googleMaps: GoogleMaps
            ) {
  }

loadMap() {

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
        target: {
          lat: 43.0741904,
          lng: -89.3809802
        },
        zoom: 18,
        tilt: 30
      }
    };

    this.map = this.googleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);

    // Wait the MAP_READY before using any methods.
    this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Map is ready!');

          // Now you can use all methods safely.
          this.map.addMarker({
            title: 'Ionic',
            icon: 'blue',
            animation: 'DROP',
            position: {
              lat: 43.0741904,
              lng: -89.3809802
            }
          })
              .then(marker => {
                marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK)
                    .subscribe(() => {
                      alert('clicked');
                    });
              });

        });
  }
```

As mentioned I installed the plugin with these 2 commands :

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps
npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps
```

Of course I specified my Android and iOS API keys.

From the `package.json`, `@ionic-native/google-maps` version 4.3.3 and the `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` version is 2.1.1

When my page loads, I have my div which is blank. When I trigger the little button to load the map, I have a console log saying "Map is ready", no error, and my requests are present on the API console

[image]

There is not the shape of the map, there is no Google logo, there is just a blank screen, nothing loads.

Thank in advance for any help !

Comment: try to set the width and height of the map_canvas-div explicitly.

Comment: I had so much trouble with ionic native maps, so I just added the JavaScript library in index.html with the API key. And declared 'maps' in my page.

Comment: It's the API Key Issue(We should use https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform generating API Key for Android and IOS other than the link in the guide). I had the same issue when following the guide. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50709647/ionic3-ionic-native-google-maps-doesnt-show-map-but-only-google-logo-display-g

Answer (score 2):

To add Ionic Native to your app, run following command to install the core package:

`npm install @ionic-native/core --save`

Keep in mind that many ionic Native Plugins only works with [real device](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/). It will not work if you run on web.

You can [check this up](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.p) for more information about using google map with ionic 2.

Comment: The article of `joshmorony.com` is too old.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: Wow, that was a nice and clear reference. Updated the answer with your reference.