# Ionic3 ionic native google maps doesn't show map but only google logo (display grey blank map )

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform, ionic3, ionic-native

**Update**

Thanks for the answer of [wf9a5m75](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697856/wf9a5m75). I had a concept misunderststand on the API Keys. **The Android and IOS API Key are generated from Google Cloud Platform Console
(https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/).**  I was using https://console.developers.google.com/ which is for Google Maps Javascript and that's why when I test the API Key on web application it works but not for mobiles.

***For anyone who follows the [Ionic native google maps guide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.g282d0a7bfd_0_186), use https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform to generate your key***

[image]

**Original Question:**

[image]

Ionic native google maps don't show map properly.
I followed [Ionic native google maps guide](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.g282d0a7bfd_0_127)
I have installed latest ionic native google maps using:

```
npm install @ionic-native/google-maps
```

Added API key by

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps \
  --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..." \
  --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..."
```

Enabled Maps SDK for both Android and IOS.

I tested with `ionic cordova run ios -l -c --target="iPhone-7"`

Have spend a couple of hours removing all packages and platforms and re-add them, nothing works

**I searched online it says the incorrect API KEY causes this issue but I tried the same key on a web application which can show map correctly.**

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gray map is always api key problem.
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.3.0/api_key/README.md

Comment: Hey wf9a5m75 Thanks for your reply. I have tried the same API Key for both web application and mobile apps, it works for the web application

Comment: `cordova-plugin-googlemaps` does not use Google Maps JavaScript v3. You need to generate api keys for Android and iOS applications.

Comment: MANY THANKS! What a mistake I have been made!

Comment: Just notice you're the author of ionic native google maps. Can you please update page https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/api_key/generate_api_key.md?

Comment: updated! Also I'm creating trouble shooting pages. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/tree/master/troubleshootings